# Login with facebook php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I'm using *Facebook PHP SDK* for authentication and i receive this message:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Error validating verification code. Please make sure
                  your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in 
                  the OAuth dialog request",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100
    }
}
```

Comment: both redirect_uri paramaters to authorize and access_token must match.

Comment: what are the url set in facebook application..??? if you use locahost then set uri in facebook application accordingly.